# Store file in Mongo's GridFS with ExpressJS after upload

Tags: mongodb, express, gridfs

I have started building a REST api using expressJS. I am new to node so please bear with me. I want to be able to let users upload a file directly to Mongo's GridFS using a post to the /upload route.

From what I understand in expressJS documentation the req.files.image object is available in the route after uploading, which also includes a path and filename attribute. But how can I exactly read the image data and store it into GridFS?

I have looked into [gridfs-stream](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream) but I can't tie ends together. Do I first need to read the file and then use that data for the writestream pipe? Or can I just use the file object from express and use those attributes to construct a writestream? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's a simple demo:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');
var mongo   = require('mongodb');
var Grid    = require('gridfs-stream');
var db      = new mongo.Db('test', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017), { safe : false });

db.open(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  var gfs = Grid(db, mongo);
  var app = express();

  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var tempfile    = req.files.filename.path;
    var origname    = req.files.filename.name;
    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: origname });
    // open a stream to the temporary file created by Express...
    fs.createReadStream(tempfile)
      .on('end', function() {
        res.send('OK');
      })
      .on('error', function() {
        res.send('ERR');
      })
      // and pipe it to gfs
      .pipe(writestream);
  });

  app.get('/download', function(req, res) {
    // TODO: set proper mime type + filename, handle errors, etc...
    gfs
      // create a read stream from gfs...
      .createReadStream({ filename: req.param('filename') })
      // and pipe it to Express' response
      .pipe(res);
  });

  app.listen(3012);
});
```

I use [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie) to upload a file:

```
http --form post localhost:3012/upload filename@~/Desktop/test.png
```

You can check your database if the file is uploaded:

```
$ mongofiles list -d test
connected to: 127.0.0.1
test.png    5520
```

You can also download it again:

```
http --download get localhost:3012/download?filename=test.png
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, thanks so much! Do you, by any chance, have any source for further documentation on this?

Comment: There's a pretty nice handbook of how streams work [here](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook). When you have an idea on how they work, I think most of the code I posted becomes easier to understand :)

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me. Also, for those using Mongoose, the only change you need to make in the above is: var gfs = Grid(db, mongoose.mongo);

Comment: @MikePateras thanks for the tip, I'm going to be using GridFS in combination with Mongoose soon myself so it's gonna save me some looking up ;)

Comment: I am following the code for download, but not working. any working example of full code?

Comment: @vinesh it's an old answer, perhaps create a new question with your exact problems?

Comment: @robertklep Good suggestion. I have asked question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623596/mean-serve-file-from-gridfs

Comment: @robertklep , Where can we configure the name of the table in test ? cause the deault is table fs.files and fs.files.

Comment: @Mr.RajivKumar `gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: origname, root : 'your_table_name' })` (that would create `your_table_name.files` and `your_table_name.chunks`). See [the documentation](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream#createwritestream).

Comment: Sir can you please open a chat ? I really wanted to ask question on you since you are expert in grid fs

Comment: I am using keystone JS there already a connection that is stablished , how can we get rid of var db      = new mongo.Db('test', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017), { safe : false }); and also db.open

Comment: so that we will no longer be defining the connections

Comment: @Mr.RajivKumar I don't have time to chat right now, sorry :( But it seems to me that you should post a new question where you explain your situation and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am using my stablished connecion but i am receiving grid.mongo.ObjectID is not a constructor

Comment: d you have a complete sample on getting the file like setting mime type + filename, handle errors, etc...

Comment: @robertklep , how can we avoid duplicates in mongo grid fs Sir?

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin please stop asking your questions in comments. Create a new question here on StackOverflow.